# Waiting for threadpool to complete execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool

I am new to threading . I have searched many questions related to my problem but I am not able to find the right solution for me. What I am doing is I am using four async tasks to fetch data from four different social media using the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. 
code is as follows.

```
new Fb().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
new Twitter().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
...

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),
                (ArrayList<Model>) showList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I want the calls to be in parallel to save the time of fetching data. Now the idea is that i want all the four threads to complete the work and after that I want to display the sorted data as per timestamp. Right now the problem is that my setAdapter get called before the four threads complete fetching data as adapter is set on the UI thread. I want a mechanism to block the UI thread until all four threads complete fetching the data.

I have found that maybe I can use the shutDown() and awaitTermination() methods of ExecutorService . It would be great if anyone can help me in anyway. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are right. shutDown or awaitTermination. You can also extend thread class and create your own messaging of threads and re-use same threads if there are many threads to be create. Maybe java optimizes thread creation out with a persistent thread to avoid creation overhead so using executor can be efficient with awaitTermination too.

Comment: If i'm understanding it correctly AsyncTask's onPostExecute(Result) should solve your problem. Once the AsyncTask finishes it calls onPostExecute on UI thread. You can keep a counter of if all tasks have finished and once they have finished you can set adapter on the list view in the onPostExecute(Result) function.

Comment: yeah I did the similar implementation. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Create an empty ArrayList in your activity
2. Pass this arrayList to your adapter and set the adapter on your ListView. setAdapter method will not affect the listView - it will still be empty becase the list is empty.
3. Start 4 AsyncTasks and fetch data. In onPostExecute() add this data to the ArrayList and invoke notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter.

You should never block an UI thread because it is just wrong. When you want all data to be shown at once you can make a simple counter, make counter++ in every onPostExecute and invoke notifyDatasetChange() only when counter is 4.

Comment: This is the proper way.  It's a very bad idea to block the UI thread for anything. At best, it makes your app look ugly  because everything keeps locking up.  At worst, you'll get an ANR error.  Alternatively, you can update the adapter every time one finishes and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the adapter so the information is updated to the user quicker.

Comment: ok I got it pretty clear.I should not think of blocking the UI thread.You all are right.I tried the way @Mark told. Bt what happens is I am sorting the data frm facebook twitter etc. on the basis of created time.So first the data of anyone thread gets set frm its postExecute() then other thread completes work and it sets the data after sorting all data. so new data gets added in btwn on notifyDatasetChange() which was looking somewhat hazy. So i was thinking the other way around i.e 1)to print data only after all threads complete execution,2)sorting them 3)set adapter only once with final data

Comment: You can do as I told you. Set the adapter, start all tasks in every onPostExecute() add data to the list and make counter++. Make a method that will check if counter is 4, sort the list and use notifyDatasetChanged (you can also set the adapter here, there should be no bigger difference).

Answer (score 0):

Invoke method **shutdown()** from **ExecutorService**.

*Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're really okay with blocking the UI thread, try this:

```
new Fb().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
new Twitter().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
...

AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.shutdown();

while (!AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.isTerminated()) {}

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),
                (ArrayList<Model>) showList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In most cases though, blocking the UI thread isn't a good idea.

Comment: Ok thanks for your idea. I will try out your code :) yeaa i too agree that blocking the UI thread is nt a good idea.. Anyways I appreciate your support

Comment: AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR does not contains methods shutdown and isTerminated. They are from ExecutorService.

Comment: Whoops, I assummed AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR was an ExecutorService.  While the above code won't necessarily work, you might be able to create your own ExecutorService to do something similar.  It looks like you've already accepted an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully handle the problem without going deeo into threading. I used the simple concept of making booleans true after execution of each thread. And in the UI thread I checked for infinte time i.e

```
while(true)
{
    if(flag1 && flag2 && flag3 && flag4)
    {
       //set the adapter and make the flags false 
       break;
    }

}
```

Dont forget to make the falgs false otherwise execution will go on for indefinite time.